# PHP force class to have a certain method if class variable has been set

Tags: php, laravel, oop, laravel-5

I have a simple requirement where I want to allow a Class (Laravel Model) to define whether a controller should check whether it's allowed to be deleted or not based on a class variable like so

```
public $verify_delete = true;
```

Currently if this variable is set I *must* add the following method;

```
public function deletable()
{
    $deletable = true;

    if ($this->has_children()) {
        $deletable = false;
    }

    // ...

    return $deletable;
}
```

The first variable is simply an indication the code running this class should also run the `deletable()` method.

**So what I want is a way to force a developer to implement the `deletable()` method if they set the `$verify_delete` to true**, and throw an error if they have not done so. I don't know much about `traits` and `implements` at this stage, so I'm not sure if they're the right route to go down.

If this is not the best method to achieve what I'm after I'm all ears.

Comment: You can't set interfaces **dynamically**. The right thing to do would be to have 2 types of objects. E.g. `Object` and `ObjectDeletable` where `ObjectDeletable` implements a `Deletable` Interface

Comment: That certainly makes sense, I'll look into doing exactly this, thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should create a trait called `Deletable` or `Removeable` or something along these lines and implement this delete method there and then each model that can be deleted will `use` this trait. Not exactly what you wanted but it is the right approach.

Or

You can create an interface which will have this method inside and then each class `(model)` which implements this interface will have to implement the method, the only difference is that implementation may vary depending on the model from others

Comment: Similar to @Xatenev's comment this makes sense, so I'll definitely look into making this change, thanks.

Answer (score 1):

You question is this: can I detect if a method is callable in a class, when a specific property is set...

Other (very wise) solutions are suggesting interfaces and traits... A perfectly fine idea and a really good way to look at things.

But you can think of something like this as well:

```
public function __construct() {
    if (true === $this->verify_delete && !method_exists($this, 'deletable')) {
        throw new \Exception('Hi developer! You forgot something...');
    }
}
```

Explanation:

- on the constructor you check if the property is true.
- if the method does not exist, let's throw an exception

I think this does exactly as you ask: force the developer to implement the deletable method, when the property is set.

But to be honest, I really like those traits as well... I just wanted to give you an alternative that does the trick as well if you are not too comfortable with techniques likes interfaces, traits, etc.

Comment: Thank you for your suggestion, this could certainly be an option as well. Not quite as strict as interfaces or traits seem to be, but could certainly work.